# How to execute sbt tasks inside Play projects cloned from git to a single directory under Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, playframework-2.0, sbt

Currently the HudsonPluginForPlay doesn't support Play 2.x and the author hasn't updated the plugin for quite some time. So I'm trying to figure out a way to get the build automated and tested on my own using sbt-launcher plugin as highlighted by [Play framework 2.0 continuous integration setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10398543/1305344).

However, I've run into a problem where my git checkout structure is like this,

```
project/
    project1/ (Play project 1)
    project2/ (Play project 2)
```

Now sbt seems to run on the root under `project/` and it doesn't do anything.

Is there a way to get it to say, run the sbt commands under `project1/` and then `project2/`? I tried using shell command to `cd` into the directories but that doesn't seem to do anything in particular.

Comment: There are subprojects in SBT. Haven't used them myself so I can only refer you to: http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Multi-Project (also added the SBT tag)

Answer (score 0):

You may be quite successful doing the following:

```
(cd project1; sbt package); (cd project2; sbt package)
```

to execute `package` command inside the projects. It has in fact nothing to do with sbt since I've only leveraged the fact you build the projects on Unix and just `cd` to each project.

There's not much you can do with sbt since defining the projects as submodules or a parent project would disable `project`-part of each Play project's build, i.e. sbt can also be defined via a Scala code inside `project/` directory inside a sbt project, but it can only be inside the root project. If you've defined the directory `project` as the root project the submodules may be damaged.